# Get id of an official twitter button in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of twitter buttons. These are added dynamically and have dynamic ids. These id are not the same when trying to access them from jquery. The client id mode is static. The ids disappear when i attach the twitter class to the buttons. The class makes the connection with twitter so this has to be included.

Does anyone have a work around?

Comment: uh, can't you use the class as the selector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [jQuery's class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/):

```
$(".[YourTwitterClassName]").each(function() {
    var currentID = $(this).attr("id");
});
```